# Finding standard Sql Server dll files on the computer

Tags: dll, sql-server-2000, extended-procedures

I am trying to add an extended stored procedure to Sql Server. I need to put the code for it in the same folder as the standard Sql Server dll files.  I know the default place that they're stored is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Mssql\Binn, but that folder doesn't exist on the computer running Sql Server.

How can I find out exactly where the standard dll files are stored?

Answer (score 0):

It's stored in the registry and can be in one of several different locations.  If SQL Server is installed as the Default instance, then it is located here.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup\SQLPath
```

If SQL Server is installed as a named instance, then it is located here.  Just replace the word INSTANCE with the actual name of the instance.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\INSTANCE\Setup\SQLPath.
```

**Note** The first registry value works with SQL Server 7 and 2000.  The second only works with SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0):

If you just search "binn" in the "Microsoft SQL Server" folder, you can find it.